# Inserting date and text values into a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, r

I want to fill up certain fields in a MySQL database. I am running into some issues however.

I want to store a character string and a data.

Therefore I defined the columns `columName` as `date` and `name` as `VARCHAR(50)`.

When I connect to the database and enter:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "INSERT INTO teamsStreak(columnName, name) VALUES(2012-10-12, test)")
```

I got this error however:

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :  could not run statement:
>   Unknown column 'test' in 'field list'

When I enter my values between quotes also nothing happens.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can be reasons for \`Error in .local(conn, statement, ...)´ in dbWriteTable from package MonetDB.R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344118/what-can-be-reasons-for-error-in-localconn-statement-%c2%b4-in-dbwritetable)

Comment: What do you get when run `dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from teamsStreak LIMIT 1")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put date and name in single quotes '' as both columns are varchar

```
dbGetQuery(con, "INSERT INTO teamsStreak(columnName, name) VALUES('2012-10-12', 'test')")
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `''` this

```
dbGetQuery(con, "INSERT INTO teamsStreak(columnName, name) VALUES('2012-10-12', 'test')");
```